# How does ruby serialization (Marshaling) work?

Tags: ruby, serialization

I have found some info on the subject ([like this link)](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/object_serialization.html), but nothing that tells me how it actually works under the covers.  If you don't want to read the essay below, here are the real questions:

1. How should I implement the `marshal_dump` and `marshal_load` methods?  even a simple example will do.
2. when `marshal_load` is called, how does it 'know' which type of object to create?  If there are multiple objects of the same type in the file, how do you tell which is which?  I am obviously confused...
3. if I have an object which represents an image, is there a different way to write it out to disk?

**My specific problem is this:**

It is a bit complicated because I do not have the source code for the object I wish to serialize.

I am working on a mod to a game engine (RPG Maker VX using the RGSS2 game library).  There is a class called Bitmap which belongs to the (closed source) API.  I would like to save this object/image between game plays, so I need to serialize it to the save file.  I'm not a ruby pro, but I know that I can define two methods (`marshal_dump` and `marshal_load`) which will be called by the "Marshal" module when I attempt to serialize the object.

The problem is that I do not know how to implement the two methods needed.  I can actually just leave them as empty methods and it *seems* to work, but the object is actually disposed and the image data is gone.  Besides that, I don't understand what it is doing internally and obviously creating empty methods is just wrong.

So can anyone tell me how this stuff works internally?  I think that would help me to solve my problem.  Beyond that, is there another type of image format that I can use which I could just save to a file and avoid doing my own serialization?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Ruby marshalling methods store the type of the object they're encoding. The way those two hooks work is like this:

- `marshal_dump` has to return some data describing the state of your object. Ruby couldn't care less about the format of this data — it just has to be something that your `marshal_load` method can use to reconstruct the object's state.
- `marshal_load` is called on the marshalled object just after it's been recreated. It's basically the initialize method for a marshalled object. It's passed whatever object `marshal_dump` returned and has to use that data to reconstruct its state.

Here's an example:

```
class Messenger

  attr_accessor :name, :message

  def marshal_dump
    {'name' => name, 'message' => message}
  end

  def marshal_load(data)
    self.name = data['name']
    self.message = data['message']
  end

end
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  That is pretty much what I thought, but I did not know that marshal_load was passed the data, I thought it was passed the entire serialized file.  Thanks again, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize raw numerical data using NArray as follows:

```
require 'narray'

class NArray
  def _dump level
    Marshal.dump [to_s, typecode] + shape
  end

  def self._load arg
    NArray.to_na *Marshal.load(arg)
  end
end

describe NArray do
  let(:arr) { NArray[[2, 3, 5], [7, 11, 13]] }

  it 'should load and save an array' do
    dumped = Marshal.dump arr
    expect(Marshal.load(dumped)).to eq arr
  end
end
```