# Safely loading a hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, file-io, hash, yaml

I want to load a data structure into a Ruby script which maps a string to a triple which contains some combination of regular expressions, scripts and atoms. The file that it loads from needs to be human writeable.

Currently I'm writing the file to contain a Ruby hash, loading that as a string and calling eval. Ie.

**Data file**

```
{ "key1" => [ /pattern/, "text", "text" ],
  "key2" => [ "text2", :nil, "text3" ],
  "key3" => [ "text4", /pattern2/, /pattern3/ ] }
```

**Script**

```
def get_mapping
  f = File.new path
  return eval(f.read())
end
```

This is fine and works, but feels (i) like a bit of a hack, (ii) unsafe. So I'm curious to know: is there a better way of doing this?

It's almost JSON but I don't think that can handle atoms or regular expressions easily. The file format can be changed as look as it remains reasonably human read/writeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should really be using YAML for this sort of stuff, your code is really risky.

YAML [supports regexps](http://yaml4r.sourceforge.net/doc/page/objects_in_yaml.htm) and is fairly extensible.

Comment: Risk is mitigated by the environment it's used it for the most part, though yes, in general, I agree. 

YAML is almost ideal by the looks of it, just wish I didn't have to to "!ruby/regexp".

Answer (score 1):

`Hash`es and `Array`s can be [marshalled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410186/how-does-ruby-serialization-marshaling-work). This might be helpful if you want to store data from your program in a file. If you are interested in giving user a chance to provide data in external file you can take a look at [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML).